# Convert dBase Timestamp

Tags: timestamp, dbase

I am trying to convert a dBase .dbf File to a mySQL Database... Its pretty straight forward, but I am stuck at the Timestamp, that is used in my .dbf Database...

Here are some Timestamps + the corresponding Date and Time Values:

```
41594.722222222 -   16.11.2013, 17:20   3472222
41594.725694444 -   16.11.2013, 17:25   3472223
41594.729166667 -   16.11.2013, 17:30   3472222
41594.732638889 -   16.11.2013, 17:35   3472222
41594.736111111 -   16.11.2013, 17:40   3472222
41594.739583333 -   16.11.2013, 17:45   3472223
41594.743055556 -   16.11.2013, 17:50   3472222
41594.746527778 -   16.11.2013, 17:55   3472222
41594.75        -   16.11.2013, 18:00   3472222
41594.753472222 -   16.11.2013, 18:05   3472222
41594.756944444 -   16.11.2013, 18:10   3472223
41594.760416667 -   16.11.2013, 18:15
41594.763888889 -   16.11.2013, 18:20
41594.767361111 -   16.11.2013, 18:25
41594.770833333 -   16.11.2013, 18:30
41594.774305556 -   16.11.2013, 18:35
41594.777777778 -   16.11.2013, 18:40
41594.78125     -   16.11.2013, 18:45
41594.784722222 -   16.11.2013, 18:50
```

The first Value (x.y) is the Timestamp as it is stored in my .dbf File. The second Value is the corresponding Date_Time Value. The third Value is the Difference between the actual and the next Timestamp (5 minutes^^)

I already found some hints on this Page:
http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm

It says: "8 bytes - two longs, first for date, second for time. The date is the number of days since 01/01/4713 BC. Time is hours * 3600000L + minutes * 60000L + Seconds * 1000L"

I am not quite sure, if it fits for my timestamp format^^ when i try to convert the days(41594) to years and start counting from "01/01/4713 BC.", i am getting not even close to 2013 :D

So, does anyone have any idea, how to convert this type of timestamp into a readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start count from 12/31/1899 instead of 01/01/4713 BC.

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[64]; double dd; int hh,mm1,sec,yy,mm,day;
long days,secs;
buf[0]=0x42; buf[1]=0xcc; buf[2]=0xb2; buf[3]=0x0e;
buf[4]=0x03; buf[5]=0x04; buf[6]=0xdf; buf[7]=0x00;
memswap((char*)&dd,(char*)&buf,8);
dd = dd / 1000.0;
days = (long) (dd / 86400);
secs = (long) fmod(dd, 86400);
SdnToGregorian(days+1721425, &yy, &mm, &day);
hh = secs/3600;
mm1 = secs/60%60;
sec = secs%60;
sprintf( s, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
            yy, mm, day, hh, mm1, sec);
puts(s);
```